# Meteor click event value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

Current target value is undefined in meteor event without selector.

HTML:

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> Child class="col-30" value="picture"}}
  {{> Child class="col-70" value="video"}}
</template>

<template name="Child">
  <div class="{{class}}">
     <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{value}}" />
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.Child.events({
  'click': function (event, template) {
    console.log(event.Target.type.value); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
Template.Child.events({
  'click .my-div-or-input-class-name-here': function (event, template) {
    console.log($(event.currentTarget).val());
  }
});
```

Is there any reason for this? Also what element do you want to click? Div or input? Input is hidden.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I need to pass some parameters to the events that parameter should not be in display, so I made it in hidden field. But is there any way to do it in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Meteor uses jQuery in core but if you need you could do console.log(e.currentTarget.value) It should work too.

Comment: in your code you mentioned `my-div-or-input-class-name-here` selector. But  in my case my selector is dynamic.

Comment: selector can be the input element or div element too, this is only an example... it depends what you need

Comment: Replace your code from this "console.log(event.Target.type.value);" To  "console.log($('[name=type]').val());" This should definately work. Let me know if you managed to resolve it in any other way.